# Match strings with partial matching allowed but only when there's a unique match

Tags: r, string, match, grepl

I have a vector of `names` and another vector `v` that I need to match against `names`. I want to receive the indices of `names` where `v` matches. Partial matching should be allowed, but only when the partial match is unique.

The following example covers all relevant cases:

```
names <- c("a", "b", "c", "ab", "def", "defg", "hij")

v1 <- c("a", "b")
v2 <- c("a", "ab")
v3 <- c("d")
v4 <- c("h")
v5 <- c("a", "b", "a")
```

I expect the following outputs:

```
match_names(v1, names)
# c(1, 2)
match_names(v2, names)
# c(1, 4)
match_names(v3, names)
# error
match_names(v4, names)
# 7
match_names(v5, names)
# c(1, 2, 1)
```

How can I write such a function? I thought about (combinations) of `which` and `grep` but did not find something useful till now?

---

**What I tried**

(*Before knowing the requirement of partial matches..*)

```
match_names1 <- function(v, names) {
  sapply(v, function(i) which(i == names))
}
```

This worked fine for examples `v1`, `v2` and `v5`.

---

After getting the requirement of partial matches

```
match_names2 <- function(v, names) {
  sapply(v, function(i) grep(i, names))
}
```

..which of course only works for `v4`

---

To catch `v3` worked with the following extension of `match_names1`:

```
match_names3 <- function(v, names) {
  exact <- match_names1(v, names)
  assertthat::assert_that(class(exact) != "list")
  return(exact)
}
```

So this covers `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and `v5`, but not `v4`

---

Thx in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[` can be used to partially match one name at a time:

```
f = function(v){
  sapply(v, function(x) setNames(seq_along(names), names)[[x, exact=FALSE]])
}

# try it on the example
vs = list(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
for (i in seq_along(vs)){
  cat("\nv", i, ":\n", sep="")
  print(try( f(vs[[i]]) ))
}
```

which yields

```
v1:
a b 
1 2 

v2:
 a ab 
 1  4 

v3:
Error in setNames(seq_along(names), names)[[x, exact = FALSE]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
[1] "Error in setNames(seq_along(names), names)[[x, exact = FALSE]] : \n  subscript out of bounds\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in setNames(seq_along(names), names)[[x, exact = FALSE]]: subscript out of bounds>

v4:
h 
7 

v5:
a b a 
1 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I opted for lists as from your question it is unclear what should happen if a string from `v` is matched exactly more than once in `names` and the only way to keep all exact matches is to return a list. If you dont like the lists you can simply `unlist()` the result.

```
match_names <- function(v, names){
    # check exact matches:
    resList <- lapply(v, function(elt) which(names == elt))

    notMatched <- which(lengths(resList) == 0) 
    if (length(notMatched) == 0) return (resList)

    #partial matching
    else{
        resNotMatched <- lapply(v[notMatched], grep, x = names)
        matchedOnce <- which(lengths(resNotMatched) == 1) 
    }

    resList[notMatched[matchedOnce]] <- resNotMatched[matchedOnce]
    return (resList)
}
```

```
> match_names(v1, names)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

> # c(1, 2)
> match_names(v2, names)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4

> # c(1, 4)
> match_names(v3, names)
[[1]]
integer(0)

> # error
> match_names(v4, names)
[[1]]
[1] 7

> # 7
> match_names(v5, names)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 1

>
```

Answer (score 1):

`match` function should work in all cases except for the partial match `v4`.
To cater for partial match, you could define a function something like:

```
match_names <- function(v, names) {

  ind <- match(v, names)

  # If can't find the match then try partial matching
  if (any(is.na(ind))) { 

    # grepl to find partial matching index
    ind <- which(grepl(v, names))

    # To ensure partial matched value is unique.
    if (length(ind) > 1) ind <- NA

  }

  return(ind)

}

> match_names(v1, names)
[1] 1 2
> match_names(v2, names)
[1] 1 4
> match_names(v3, names)
[1] NA
> match_names(v4, names)
[1] 7
> match_names(v5, names)
[1] 1 2 1
```